# Lua: Help function: Can I extract the name of a function?

Tags: lua, documentation

I would like to learn by developing a help function. The code below outlines my plan, and it can be summarized as:

1. For functions defined in Lua files - look for comments in the source.
2. For built-in functions and DLLs - look for a text file in .\help\function.txt.
3. For libraries (if no comments in the source) - look for a text file in .\lib\help\function.txt.

At the end of my code you can see an attempt to build an index of function names using their unique `tostring(function)` return value. Surely I should be able to do this in a loop?

```
    function learn()
    -- learn()
    --     Make it easier to learn Lua, based upon Matlab console functions
    --     help()           print for help text in function source or help directory
    --     who()            print defined variables (exlcuding those in loaded modules)
    --     what()           print defined functions (exlcuding those in loaded modules)
    --     which()          print path to function source file if present
    --     list()           print the file to the console
    --     edit()           edit "filename" or function source if present 
    --                  note: edit(_) can be used after any call to list(), help(func), 
    -- Helper functions
    --     table.name()        returns table name as string
    --     table.length()        this is difficult
    --     table.keylist()        returns a list of keys
    --     table.keytype()        returns a list of key types
    --     edit_source()        process function names
    --     edit_new()           create new "filename" (will use but not make subdirectories)
    --     string.split()        returns a table from a string
    --     io.exists()          test if a filename exists
    --     io.newfile()         creates an empty file
    --
    -- global variables
    --    editor = "P:\\MyPrograms\\EDITORS\\Addins\\Editor2\\editor2.exe "
    --    helpindex a list of the names of the inbuilt functions - see end of file
    --  topics        a table of help topics see topics.lua
    --  web = "web"
        web = "web"
    --  webhelp = "http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/doc/"
        webhelp = "http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/doc/"
    --  editor = "P:\\MyPrograms\\EDITORS\\Addins\\Editor2\\editor2.exe "
        editor = "P:\\MyPrograms\\EDITORS\\Addins\\Editor2\\editor2.exe "
    -- required packages    
    --    lfs         - lua file system (binary from lua-files)
        require("lfs")  
    --  topics  - for the help system   
        require("topics")
    end 

    learn()


    function who(t,i)
    -- who(table) 
    --  searches the table (or defaults to _G) to print a list of table keys + types
    --  the second parameter is to add a prefix for a recursive call to search "sub" tables
    --  still having difficulty with the "loaded" table as this is self referencing and sets up an infinate loop!
    --  designed for the console, but could be modified to return a table
    --
        if type(t)~="table" then 
            t=_G 
        end

        if type(i)~="string" then
            i=""
        end

        local s={}
        local u={}

        s = table.keylist(t)
        u = table.keytype(t)

        for k,v in ipairs(s) do
            if u[k]=="table" and s[k]~="_G" and s[k]~="loaded" then
                who(t[s[k]],i..v..".")
            else
                if u[k]~="table" and u[k]~="function" and u[k]~="cdata" then
                    print(u[k], i..v)
                end
            end
        end
    end

    function what(t,i)
    -- what(table) 
    --  searches the table (or defaults to _G) to print a list of function names
    --  the second parameter is to add a prefix for a recursive call to search "sub" tables
    --  still having difficulty with the "loaded" table as this is self referencing and sets up an infinate loop!
    --  designed for the console, but could be modified to return a table
    --
        if type(t)~="table" then 
            t=_G 
        end

        if type(i)~="string" then
            i=""
        end

        local s={}
        local u={}

        s = table.keylist(t)
        u = table.keytype(t)

        for k,v in ipairs(s) do
            if u[k]=="table" and s[k]~="_G" and s[k]~="loaded" then
                what(t[s[k]],i..v..".")
            else
                if u[k]=="function" then
                    print(u[k], i..v)
                end
            end
        end
    end

    function which(funcname)
    -- which(funcname) 
    --  identifies the source for the current definition of funcname
    --  designed for the console, but could be modified to return a string
    --
        if type(funcname)~="function" then return end

        local filename = _G.debug.getinfo(funcname).short_src
        if filename=="[C]" then
            print(tostring(funcname))
        else
            return filename
        end
    end

    function help(funcname)
    -- help(object)
    --  for functions prints help text (from source or help\function.txt)
    --      adding help text to source as ^--comments is recommended, 
    --      for builtin functions use a subdirectory from the executable,
    --      for uncommented source add a sibling help directory 
    --  for table prints table name, size and list of contents
    --  for variables prints the type of the object 
    --
        if type(funcname)=="boolean" then
            io.write("boolean: ")
            print(funcname)
            return
        end

        if type(funcname)=="string" then
            if funcname=="web" then
                os.launch(webhelp)
            else
                print("string: "..funcname)
            end
            return
        end

        if type(funcname)=="number" then
            print("number: "..funcname)
            return
        end

        if type(funcname) == 'userdata' then
            print(tostring(funcname))
            io.write("metadata: ")
            print(getmetatable(funcname))
        end 

        if type(funcname) == 'cdata' then
            print(tostring(funcname))
            -- *** Unfinished
        end

        if type(funcname)=="table" then 
            print(tostring(funcname)..", size: "..table.length(funcname))
            who(funcname)
            what(funcname)
            return 
        end

        if type(funcname)=="function" then 

            -- Test for a source file
            local filename = _G.debug.getinfo(funcname).short_src
            if io.exists(filename) then
                local codestart = _G.debug.getinfo(funcname).linedefined
                local codeend = _G.debug.getinfo(funcname).lastlinedefined

                if codestart < 1 then
                    print("Start is less than 1")
                    codestart = 1
                end

                if codeend< 1 then
                    print("End is less than 1")
                    codeend= 100
                end

                -- Try to read comments from the source
                local output = 0        
                local count = 0
                for line in io.lines(filename) do 
                    count = count+1
                    if count > codestart and count < codeend then
                        if line:match("^%-%-") then
                            print(line)
                            output = output + 1
                        end
                    end
                end         
                if output>0 then
                    io.write("From : ")
                    return filename -- to be used with edit(_)
                end

                -- Test for a help file as a sibling of the source
                if output==0 then
                    -- No comments in the source file so look for a help file
                    local t = string.split(filename, "\\")
                    local helppath = table.concat(t,"\\",1,table.length(t)-1).."\\help\\"..t[table.length(t)]
                    helppath = string.gsub(helppath, "%.lua$" , ".txt")
                    if io.exists(helppath) then
                        local filename = list(helppath)
                        io.write("From : ")
                        return filename -- to be used with edit(_)
                    else
                        print("No help in source file : "..filename)
                        io.write("No help in: ")
                        return helppath -- to be used with edit_new(_)
                    end
                end
            end 

            --  Test for a help file in the generic help directory 
            if helpindex[tostring(funcname)] then
                local helppath = "help\\"..helpindex[tostring(funcname)]..".txt"
                if io.exists(helppath) then
                    local filename = list(helppath)
                    io.write("From : ") 
                    return filename -- to be used with edit(_)
                else
                    io.write("Built in function, but no help in: ")
                    return helppath  -- to be used with edit_new(_)
                end
            else
                print("No help index entry for "..tostring(funcname))
                return
            end
        end
    end

    function list(filename)
        if type(filename)=="function" then 
            print("list will only accept a string with a valid file name")
            return
        end
        if type(filename)~="string" then 
            print("list will only accept a string with a valid file name")
            return 
        end
        if io.exists(filename) then
            for line in io.lines(filename) do 
                print(line)
            end
            return filename
        else
            io.write("Can't find file: ")
            return filename
        end 
    end

    function edit(filename, linenum)
    -- edit(filename[, linenum])
    --  loads the file into my editor (defined as global editor)
    --  the linenum parameter will move the cursor to linenum
    --  you will need to edit the global "editor" and the source command line below
    --  or download Editor²  from http://www.zabkat.com
    --
        if type(filename)=="function" then 
            filename = edit_source(filename) 
            return filename
        end

        if type(filename)~="string" then return end
        if type(linenum)~="number" then linenum=1 end

        if io.exists(filename) then
            os.launch(editor.." /P /L:"..linenum.." \""..filename.."\"", " /P /L:"..linenum.." \""..filename.."\"")
        else
            print("To make a new file edit_new('filename')")
            io.write("Can't find file: ")
            return filename
        end 
    end

    function edit_source(funcname)
        if type(funcname)~="function" then return end

        local filename = _G.debug.getinfo(funcname).short_src
        if io.exists(filename) then
            local linenum = _G.debug.getinfo(funcname).linedefined
            if linenum < 1 then
                linenum = 1
            end
            edit(filename, linenum)
            io.write("Editing : ")
            return filename
        end
    end

    function edit_new(filename)
        if type(filename)~="string" then return end
        io.newfile(filename)
        edit(filename) -- This will check for a valid file name
        io.write("Editing : ")
        return filename
    end

    function table.name(table)
        if type(table)~="table" then return end
        for k, v in pairs(_G) do
            if v == table then
                return k
            end
        end
        return nil
    end

    function table.length(table)
        if type(table)~="table" then return end

        local len = 0 

        for _ in pairs(table) do 
            len = len + 1 
        end

        if type(len)=="number" then 
            return len
        else
            return nil
        end
    end

    function table.keylist(table)
        if type(table)~="table" then return end

        local keylist={}
        local n=0
        for key in pairs(table) do
            n=n+1 
            keylist[n]=key
        end
        return keylist
    end

    function table.keytype(table)
        if type(table)~="table" then return end

        local keytype={}
        local n=0
        for key in pairs(table) do
            n=n+1 
            keytype[n]=type(table[key])
        end
        return keytype
    end

    function table.tablelist(table)
        if type(table)~="table" then return end

        local tablelist={}
        local n=0
        for key in pairs(table) do
            if type(table[key])=="table" then
                n=n+1 
                tablelist[n]=key
            end
        end
        return tablelist
    end

    function string.split(inputstr, sep)
            if sep == nil then
                    sep = "%s"
            end

            local t={}
            local i=1

            for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..sep.."]+)") do
                    t[i] = str
                    i = i + 1
            end
            return t
    end

    function  io.newfile(filename)
    -- io.newfile(filename)
    --  Will create a file if this is a valid filename
    --  relative paths will work
    --  files will not be overwritten
        if type(filename)~="string" then 
            print("This function requires a string")
            return 
        end
        if io.exists(filename) then
            io.write("This file already exists : ")
            return filename
        end
        file, errormsg = io.open(filename, "w")
        if errormsg then
            print(errormsg)
        else
            file:write()
            file:close()

            io.write("New file created : ")
            return filename
        end
    end

    function io.exists(filename)
        if type(filename)~="string" then return false end

        local f=io.open(filename,"r")

        if f~=nil then
            io.close(f) return true
        else 
            return false 
        end
    end

    function    os.launch(command,params)
        -- Via a dos box works - but flashes up a dos console
        --    would  love a way round this problem
        command = "start "..command
        os.execute(command)
    end

    helpindex =  {
                    [tostring(assert)] = "assert",
                    [tostring(collectgarbage)] = "collectgarbage", 
                    [tostring(dofile)] = "dofile", 
                    [tostring(error)] = "error", 
                    [tostring(getfenv)] = "getfenv",
                    [tostring(getmetatable)] = "getmetatable", 
                    [tostring(ipairs)] = "ipairs",
                    [tostring(load)] = "load",
                    [tostring(loadfile)] = "loadfile",
                    [tostring(loadstring)] = "loadstring",
                    [tostring(next)] = "next" ,
                    [tostring(pairs)] = "pairs" ,
                    [tostring(pcall)] = "pcall" ,
                    [tostring(rawequal)] = "rawequal" ,
                    [tostring(rawget)] = "rawget" ,
                    [tostring(rawset)] = "rawset" ,
                    [tostring(select)] = "select" ,
                    [tostring(setfenv)] = "setfenv" ,
                    [tostring(setmetatable)] = "setmetatable" ,
                    [tostring(tonumber)] = "tonumber" ,
                    [tostring(tostring)] = "tostring" ,
                    [tostring(type)] = "type" ,
                    [tostring(unpack)] = "unpack" ,
                    [tostring(xpcall)] = "xpcall" ,
                    [tostring(coroutine.create)] = "coroutine.create" ,
                    [tostring(coroutine.resume)] = "coroutine.resume" ,
                    [tostring(coroutine.running)] = "coroutine.running" ,
                    [tostring(coroutine.status )] = "coroutine.status ",
                    [tostring(coroutine.wrap)] = "coroutine.wrap" ,
                    [tostring(coroutine.yield)] = "coroutine.yield" ,
                    [tostring(string.byte)] = "string.byte" ,
                    [tostring(string.char)] = "string.char" , 
                    [tostring(string.dump)] = "string.dump" , 
                    [tostring(string.find )] = "string.find",
                    [tostring(string.format)] = "string.format" , 
                    [tostring(string.gmatch)] = "string.gmatch" ,
                    [tostring(string.gsub)] = "string.gsub" ,
                    [tostring(string.len)] = "string.len" ,
                    [tostring(string.lower)] = "string.lower" ,
                    [tostring(string.match)] = "string.match" ,
                    [tostring(string.rep)] = "string.rep" ,
                    [tostring(string.reverse)] = "string.reverse" ,
                    [tostring(string.sub)] = "string.sub" ,
                    [tostring(string.upper)] = "string.upper" ,
                    [tostring(table.concat)] = "table.concat" ,
                    [tostring(table.insert)] = "table.insert" ,
                    [tostring(table.maxn)] = "table.maxn" ,
                    [tostring(table.remove)] = "table.remove" ,
                    [tostring(table.sort)] = "table.sort" ,
                    [tostring(math.abs)] = "math.abs" , 
                    [tostring(math.acos)] = "math.acos" ,
                    [tostring(math.asin)] = "math.asin" ,
                    [tostring(math.atan)] = "math.atan" , 
                    [tostring(math.atan2)] = "math.atan2" ,
                    [tostring(math.ceil)] = "math.ceil" ,
                    [tostring(math.cos)] = "math.cos" ,
                    [tostring(math.cosh)] = "math.cosh" ,
                    [tostring(math.deg)] = "math.deg" ,
                    [tostring(math.exp)] = "math.exp" ,
                    [tostring(math.floor)] = "math.floor" ,
                    [tostring(math.fmod)] = "math.fmod" ,
                    [tostring(math.frexp)] = "math.frexp" ,
                    [tostring(math.ldexp)] = "math.ldexp" ,
                    [tostring(math.log)] = "math.log" ,
                    [tostring(math.log10)] = "math.log10" ,
                    [tostring(math.max)] = "math.max" , 
                    [tostring(math.min)] = "math.min" ,
                    [tostring(math.modf)] = "math.modf" ,
                    [tostring(math.pow)] = "math.pow" ,
                    [tostring(math.rad)] = "math.rad" ,
                    [tostring(math.random)] = "math.random" ,
                    [tostring(math.randomseed)] = "math.randomseed" ,
                    [tostring(math.sin)] = "math.sin" ,
                    [tostring(math.sinh)] = "math.sinh" ,
                    [tostring(math.sqrt)] = "math.sqrt" ,
                    [tostring(math.tan)] = "math.tan" ,
                    [tostring(math.tanh)] = "math.tanh" ,
                    [tostring(io.close)] = "io.close" ,
                    [tostring(io.flush)] = "io.flush" ,
                    [tostring(io.input)] = "io.input" ,
                    [tostring(io.lines)] = "io.lines" ,
                    [tostring(io.open)] = "io.open" ,
                    [tostring(io.output)] = "io.output" ,
                    [tostring(io.popen)] = "io.popen" ,
                    [tostring(io.read)] = "io.read" ,
                    [tostring(io.tmpfile)] = "io.tmpfile" , 
                    [tostring(io.type)] = "io.type" ,
                    [tostring(io.write)] = "io.write" ,
                    [tostring(os.clock)] = "os.clock" ,
                    [tostring(os.date)] = "os.date" ,
                    [tostring(os.difftime)] = "os.difftime" ,
                    [tostring(os.execute)] = "os.execute" ,
                    [tostring(os.exit)] = "os.exit" ,
                    [tostring(os.getenv)] = "os.getenv" ,
                    [tostring(os.remove)] = "os.remove" ,
                    [tostring(os.rename)] = "os.rename" ,
                    [tostring(os.setlocale)] = "os.setlocale" , 
                    [tostring(os.time)] = "os.time" ,
                    [tostring(os.tmpname)] = "os.tmpname" ,
                    [tostring(debug.debug)] = "debug.debug" ,
                    [tostring(debug.getfenv)] = "debug.getfenv" ,
                    [tostring(debug.gethook)] = "debug.gethook" ,
                    [tostring(debug.getinfo)] = "debug.getinfo" ,
                    [tostring(debug.getlocal)] = "debug.getlocal" ,
                    [tostring(debug.getmetatable)] = "debug.getmetatable" ,
                    [tostring(debug.getregistry)] = "debug.getregistry" ,
                    [tostring(debug.getupvalue)] = "debug.getupvalue" ,
                    [tostring(debug.setfenv)] = "debug.setfenv" ,
                    [tostring(debug.sethook)] = "debug.sethook" ,
                    [tostring(debug.setlocal)] = "debug.setlocal" ,
                    [tostring(debug.setmetatable)] = "debug.setmetatable" ,
                    [tostring(debug.setupvalue)] = "debug.setupvalue" ,
                    [tostring(debug.traceback)] = "debug.traceback" ,
                    [tostring(module)] = "module" ,
                    [tostring(package.loadlib)] = "package.loadlib" ,
                    [tostring(package.seeall)] = "package.seeall" ,
                    [tostring(print)] = "print" ,
                    [tostring(require)] = "require" ,
                    [tostring(graph.fxplot)] = "graph.fxplot"
                }
```

Revised code:

```
    function help(funcname)
    -- help(object)
    --  for functions prints help text (from source or help\function.txt)
    --      adding help text to source as ^--comments is recommended, 
    --      for builtin functions use a subdirectory from the executable,
    --      for uncommented source add a sibling \help directory and function.txt
    --       (note that the source file may contain several functions)
    --  for table prints table name, size and list of contents
    --  for variables prints the type of the object 
    --
        if type(funcname)=="boolean" then
            io.write("boolean: ")
            print(funcname)
            return
        end

        if type(funcname)=="string" then
            if funcname=="web" then
                os.launch(webhelp)
            else
                print("string: "..funcname)
            end
            return
        end

        if type(funcname)=="number" then
            print("number: "..funcname)
            return
        end

        if type(funcname) == 'userdata' then
            print(tostring(funcname))
            io.write("metadata: ")
            print(getmetatable(funcname))
        end 

        if type(funcname) == 'cdata' then
            print(tostring(funcname))
            -- *** Unfinished
        end

        if type(funcname)=="table" then 
            print(tostring(funcname)..", size: "..table.length(funcname))
            who(funcname)
            what(funcname)
            return 
        end

        if type(funcname)=="function" then 

            -- Test for a source file
            local filename = _G.debug.getinfo(funcname).short_src
            if io.exists(filename) then
                local codestart = _G.debug.getinfo(funcname).linedefined
                local codeend = _G.debug.getinfo(funcname).lastlinedefined

                if codestart < 1 then
                    print("Start is less than 1")
                    codestart = 1
                end

                if codeend< 1 then
                    print("End is less than 1")
                    codeend= 100
                end

                -- Try to read comments from the source
                local output = 0        
                local count = 0
                for line in io.lines(filename) do 
                    count = count+1
                    if count > codestart and count < codeend then
                        if line:match("^%-%-") then
                            print(line)
                            output = output + 1
                        end
                    end
                end         
                if output>0 then
                    io.write("From : ")
                    return filename -- to be used with edit(_)
                end

                -- Try to read comments from \help\function.txt
                if output==0 then
                    -- No comments in the source file so look for a help file
                    local t = string.split(filename, "\\")
                    local helppath = table.concat(t,"\\",1,table.length(t)-1).."\\help\\"..helpindex[funcname]..".txt"
                    if io.exists(helppath) then
                        local filename = list(helppath)
                        io.write("From : ")
                        return filename -- to be used with edit(_)
                    else
                        print("No help in source file : "..filename)
                        io.write("No help in: ")
                        return helppath -- to be used with edit_new(_)
                    end
                end
            end 

            --  Test for a help file in the generic help directory 
            if helpindex[funcname] then
                local helppath = "help\\"..helpindex[funcname]..".txt"
                if io.exists(helppath) then
                    local filename = list(helppath)
                    io.write("From : ") 
                    return filename -- to be used with edit(_)
                else
                    io.write("Built in function, but no help in: ")
                    return helppath  -- to be used with edit_new(_)
                end
            else
                print("No help index entry for "..helpindex[funcname])
                return
            end
        end
    end


    -- helpindex as a [function literal -> string] mapping of names.
    --  many thanks to Ryan Stein 
    --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269173/lua-help-function-can-i-extract-the-name-of-a-function
    helpindex = {}
    do
        local function indexfn(t, n)
            if n == '_G' then n = '' else n = n .. '.' end

            for k, v in pairs(t) do
                if type(v) == 'function' then
                    helpindex[v] = n .. k
                end
            end
        end

        for k, v in pairs(_G) do -- Iterate all tables in global scope.
            if type(v) == 'table' then
                indexfn(v, k)
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: As you've seen, you can get such "debug" information in some cases. But in the general case, functions are values, and values don't have names. The debug stack trace gives a function a name based on how it is called. If you have a function and assign it to `x` and `y`. It'll be "named" `x` if you call it by `x()` and `y` if you call it by `y()`. If a table (including the `_G` or global table) references a function value using a string as the key, then you could name the function after the key. Locals (including parameters) can also reference functions but their names are harder to enumerate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this may be what you're looking for:

```
local helpindex = {}
do
    local function indexfn(t, n)
        if n == '_G' then n = '' else n = n .. '.' end

        for k, v in pairs(t) do
            if type(v) == 'function' then
                helpindex[v] = n .. k
            end
        end
    end

    for k, v in pairs(_G) do -- Iterate all tables in global scope.
        if type(v) == 'table' then
            indexfn(v, k)
        end
    end
end
-- helpindex is now a [function literal -> string] mapping of names.
```

---

You don't need to convert the functions to strings to use them as table keys, since anything other than `nil` can be used as a table key in Lua. The functions themselves work just fine.

Comment: Great fix, many thanks. I have altered the help function in the code above new helpindex. For others who may choose to use the script I have added the revised code.